# Updating a pandas column with a dictionary lookup

Tags: pandas

Have a dataframe, df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'elephant'] * 3

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 2), index=i, columns=list('AB'))
```

...and a lookup dict for column B:

`b_dict = {'elephant': 2.0, 'dog': 5.0}`

How can column B of df be replaced for elephant and dog rows?

`df['B'].update(b_dict)` gives:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'reindex_like'

Comment: `df['B'] = df.index.map(b_dict)` ?

Comment: @ChrisA `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: @Alex It works for me. What pandas version are you using?

Comment: @DanielMesejo 0.22, I'm in an older venv

Comment: It works in 0.23.4

Comment: @ChrisA ... df['B'].index.map(b_dict) makes the remaining nan. Don't want that. Any possibility of filling with fillna()?

Comment: yeah @anky_91's solution using `np.where` got you covered

Comment: Do df.index.map(lambda x: b_dict.get(x, x))

Comment: @Vaishali ... this is not the same question as what you have put. Here the values are looked up against the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to `pd.Series` and `update` will work

```
df['B'].update(pd.Series(b_dict))
df
Out[185]: 
                 A         B
dog      -1.340695  5.000000
cat      -0.196993 -0.021518
rabbit   -0.274504 -0.260294
elephant -0.170860  2.000000
dog      -0.432042  5.000000
cat       0.868669  0.204100
rabbit    0.435023 -1.968735
elephant -0.668397  2.000000
dog       0.706603  5.000000
cat       0.158067  0.675130
rabbit    0.429419  0.374914
elephant  1.559330  2.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace only where condition matches and retain the rest:

```
df['B']=np.where(df.index.isin(b_dict.keys()),df.index.map(b_dict),df.B)
```

Comment: I've had a similar question and have been looking for an answer for about an hour - this solved my problem perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
cond = [(df.index == x) for x in b_dict.keys()]
vals = b_dict.values()

df['B'] = np.select(cond, vals)

Out[13]:         A    B
dog       0.523732  5.0
cat      -0.923483  0.0
rabbit    0.339749  0.0
elephant  1.204516  2.0
dog       1.799287  5.0
cat       0.214085  0.0
rabbit   -1.685739  0.0
elephant -0.475113  2.0
dog       1.381671  5.0
cat       1.343616  0.0
rabbit    0.627273  0.0
elephant  0.630255  2.0
```