# Dictionary update using .update() and pd.Series doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a pandas DataFrame with a text field called "term", that has string values ' 36 months' and ' 60 months' (both with leading spaces). I'm looking to replace the strings with just the numeric piece, i.e. 36 or 60.

I'm trying to follow this post -

[Updating a pandas column with a dictionary lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652103/updating-a-pandas-column-with-a-dictionary-lookup)

Here's my code -

```
import pandas as pd
import re

loan_data = pd.read_csv('loan_data_2007_2014.csv')

# create a dictionary with the from (key) and to (value) pairs for the lookup replacement
term_set = set(loan_data['term'])
term_dict = {x: int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', x)) for x in term_set}

# term_dict => {' 36 months': 36, ' 60 months': 60} (both keys have a leading space)

loan_data['term_int'] = loan_data['term']

loan_data['term_int'].update(pd.Series(term_dict))

print("unique term_int = ", loan_data['term_int'].unique())
```

I expected the term_int field in the DataFrame to contain values 36 or 60, but the lookup didn't work.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `map` instead of `update`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

term_set = set(loan_data['term'])
term_dict = {x: int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', x)) for x in term_set}

loan_data['term_int'] = loan_data['term'].map(term_dict)
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. This worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What stands out to me is the line:
`loan_data['term_int'].update(pd.Series(term_dict))`.
I don't think `DataFrame.update()` is the correct approach. I would just apply a function to column "term" to generate a new column.